# issues with generate password by server and sms to user

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport-local

I use passport to authenticate and for sign up when I use html form there is no problem but when I try to generate a random number and put the value in passport method although the user create in data base but doesn't work!?
here is my code:

```
router.post("/register", function (req, res) {
    var password = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100000) + 1).toString();
    User.findOne().sort({
        field: 'asc',
        _id: -1
    }).limit(1).exec(function (err, lastQ) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(lastQ);
            var customersNo = Number(lastQ.customerNo) + 1;
            User.register(new User({
                username: username,
                customerNo: customersNo,
                customerName: req.body.customerName,
                customerAdd: req.body.customerAdd,
                customerPhone: req.body.customerPhone
            }), req.body.password, function (err, user) { ....//here works!
```

in part above everything OK but if change req.body.password with my variable 'password' doesn't work:

```
router.post("/register", function (req, res) {
    var password = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100000) + 1).toString();
    User.findOne().sort({
        field: 'asc',
        _id: -1
    }).limit(1).exec(function (err, lastQ) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(lastQ);
            var customersNo = Number(lastQ.customerNo) + 1;
            User.register(new User({
                username: username,
                customerNo: customersNo,
                customerName: req.body.customerName,
                customerAdd: req.body.customerAdd,
                customerPhone: req.body.customerPhone
            }), password, function (err, user) { ....//here doesn't work!
```

Answer (score 0):

What error it gives? By viewing I figured out you might missing on the scope of this.

Comment: no error just save a user in my database but when i use the user name and generated password it doesn't work! actually I can see the hash, salt and username in the database!

Comment: Had you checked and print the value in console of User to register before passing it to database? Can you figure out

Comment: C:\Users\Milad\Desktop\project\milad>node milad.js
server started
{ _id: 5901de4698abac19583bd05c,
  username: 'moon',
  customerNo: 210,
  __v: 0 }
75975<---password---
sun<---username---
string<---typeofpassword---
{ __v: 0,
  orderNo: 0,
  _id: 5901decdf4916c0324531160,
  productInfo: [],
  customerInfo: [] }<---newOrder---||!!||
its the out put but server return unautorized

Answer (score 0):

my assumption, that your password has not been generated yet is already used, maybe you can handle it with the async function,

or to be sure, try console the `password`, whether the password has been generated or not.